# Unable to display image from JSON API in Angular

Tags: json, angular, httpclient, angular-httpclient, jsonobjectrequest

JSON API

```
teams": [

    {
        "logo": "/wp-content/themes/squiggle/assets/images/Adelaide.jpg",
        "abbrev": "ADE",
        "name": "Adelaide",
        "id": 1
    },
```

component.ts

```
  teams = [];

  responseData: any

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.get("https://api.squiggle.com.au/?q=teams").subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.responseData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res))["teams"];
    },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      },
      () => {
        console.log(this.responseData);
      }
    )
  }
```

HTML File

```
 <tr *ngFor="let team of responseData">
          <td>{{team.id}}</td>
          <td>{{team.abbrev}}</td>
          <td><img [src]="{{team.logo}}" alt="image"</td>
          <td>{{team.name}}</td>
 </tr>
```

The HttpClient is working fine and display it perfectly except of the images. The image are being displayed as "/wp-content/themes/squiggle/assets/images/Adelaide.jpg". I have tried using img tag with src[] but does not seem to fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the logos are under the domain `https://squiggle.com.au` whereas the API is under `https://api.squiggle.com.au/`. So you might have to manually concatenate the domain for each element of the array. I've modified the data extraction as well using RxJS `pipe` and `map`. Try the following

```js
IMG_BASE_URL = 'https://squiggle.com.au';

ngOnInit() {
  this.http.get("https://api.squiggle.com.au/?q=teams")
    .pipe(map(teams => {
      const result = teams['teams'];
      result.forEach(team => team['logo'] = this.IMG_BASE_URL + team['logo'] );
      return result;
    }))
    .subscribe(
      res => { this.responseData = res; },
      err => { console.log(err); },
      () => { console.log(this.responseData); }
    );
}
```

Also the URL binding to `img` should either be using data binding syntax `[src]="team.logo"` or data interpolation syntax `src="{{team.logo}}"`. They shouldn't be mixed together, please notice the square brackets.

Template

```
<tr *ngFor="let team of responseData">
  <td>{{team.id}}</td>
  <td>{{team.abbrev}}</td>
  <td><img [src]="team.logo" alt="image"></td>
  <td>{{team.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: works perfect, any tutorial you would recommend related to these types of topics?

Comment: TBH the logo domain was a bit of guesswork. If you haven't gone through already, Angular tutorial (https://angular.io/tutorial) is a quick and good introduction to some basics of Angular.

Answer (score 0):

im not sure this is it but you shouldnt use "[]" and "{{}}"
try switching [src]="{{team.logo}}" for [src]="team.logo"

Answer (score 0):

you don't need interpolation with attribute binding.

```
<td><img [src]="team.logo" alt="image"</td>
```

should do the job.